# Need a little help filtering lines in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have text file which contains the follwing

```
Pool        p c Dev   Dev             Total  Enabled     Used     Free   a   b
------------ - - ----- ------------ -------- -------- -------- -------- --- ---
FC100        T F FBA   RAID-3(1+1)   13849.1  13849.1  13119.4   7292.0   0 Ena
SATA500      T S FBA   RAID-3(1+1)   50019.2  50019.2  46974.5   3044.9 Ena   0
```

I want to display extract FC100 and SATA500 from the file because those two lines contain "Ena". I have very little batch script experience so with my limited knowledge I came up with following script.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in (list.txt) DO (
    if "%%b" NEQ "" (

        set string=%%b
        set substring= Ena

        echo !string! |findstr "!substring!" > nul
        if errorlevel 1 (
            rem echo !SubString!
        ) else (
            echo %%a
        )
    )
)
```

What is happening with the above code is that I am getting the required output but I am also getting Pool because the line contains Ena in Enabled. How do extract lines which only contain Ena and not match with Enabled.

Current Output

```
Pool
FC100
SATA500
```

I tried to use some regex magic with findstr but its not working out for me. 
Note - I can solve this problem in Perl but unfortunately I cannot install Perl on the system so I have to do this in batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to match `Ena` as a whole word. To do that, you can surround your search term with `\<` and `\>`, i.e. change the `substring` assignment like this:

```
set "substring=\<Ena\>"
```

And by the way, there's probably no need to assign `substring` to the same value at every iteration of the loop. You can assign it just once before the loop.

Comment: And certainly the `findstr` command must NOT need to be executed _with every line in the file_, but just once in the loop...

Comment: Andriy, your solution worked, I will do some more testing and report back. I was under the impression that findstr would support normal regex patterns like $ or \s.

Comment: @Sumedh: It does support `$` (and `^`), but I don't think those would work for you. Not sure what `\s` is but, according to the build-in help (`findstr /?`), you are probably right, it is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1" %%a in ('findstr /C:" Ena" list.txt') do (
   echo %%a
)
```

**EDIT:** *New solution that seek for lines precisely with "Ena" string in any part*

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('findstr /R /C:"\<Ena\>" list.txt') do (
   echo %%a
)
```

Comment: What if there is another line with 'Enabled'?

Comment: Wouldn't `/C:" Ena"` match `" Enabled"` too?

Comment: Yes, but "skip=1" omit it. Although the OP said "contain Ena and not match with Enabled", I think he/she really wanted to mean "contain Ena and not match the first header line". I doubt there is any "Enabled" field into the file below the first line...

Comment: Well, we shouldn't rely on our doubts. :) However, what you said does sound plausible and `skip=1` is a clever solution indeed (I overlooked it initially).

Comment: Sometimes the header line is at line no 1, 3 or 5, there is some extra information above the header line which I omitted to keep the question simple. So I am really looking for a solution which does not depend on the line number logic.

Comment: My solution works OK if there is just ONE header line with "Enabled" word before the data (although may be several header lines). Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, there MAYBE several header lines, it varies from system to system.

Comment: Thanks Aacini, I accepted @Andriy's  solution as the answer as he came up with the solution which did not require line numbers first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set substring="Ena[^a-zA-Z]"
```

`[^a-zA-Z]` instructs `findstr` not to use strings which contain letters after `Ena`.

Comment: At the same time, your expression instructs `findstr` to match strings that contain at least one character after `Ena`. If `Ena` is at the end of a line, it won't match the search term.

Comment: Actually, it does match such lines.

Comment: It didn't for me. My test was very simple. I created a text file with three lines: `Ena1`, `Ena`, `Enab`. Running `findstr "Ena[^a-zA-Z]"` on it produced only one line: `Ena1`. It's Win XP SP3.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
echo !string! |findstr "!substring!" > nul
```

with

```
echo !string! |findstr "!substring!" |findstr /v "Enabled" > nul
```

or even simpler:

```
echo !string! |findstr "Ena" |findstr /v "Enabled" > nul
```

first `findstr` will include all lines with "Ena", second `findstr /v` will exclude all lines with "Enabled".